fatal: could not fetch SHA from promisor remote
Trying to use the treeless fetch to get all the commit history for blame attribution in Sonarqube.But end up getting the error above.
The environment is Azure devops with a hosted agent.
Git version shows - git-lfs/3.4.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.20.6; git d06d6e9e)
Tried using the instructions here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines
specifically

fetchFilter string.
Use fetchFilter to filter Git history for partial cloning. The fetchFilter setting supports treeless and blobless fetches. For a treeless fetch, specify fetchFilter: tree:0 and to specify a blobless fetch, specify fetchFilter: blob:none. The default is no filtering.

Relevant azure-pipeline.yaml section
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchFilter: tree:0

The build throws the error - fatal: could not fetch SHA from promisor remote

I can reproduce the same issue when adding the fetchFilter in the checkout step.

This could be related to the git credential when setting the fetchFilter argument. When you set the fetchFilter, the git command will not able to get the credential.
The issue is from the checkout feature itself. I suggest that you can report the issue to Developer Community. Azure DevOps Developers will investigate this feature further.
For a workaround, you can add an additional checkout step(set persistCredentials:true) before the existing checkout step to pre-config the git  credential.
For example:
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  path: storecred
- checkout: self
  clean: true
  fetchFilter: tree:0
  persistCredentials: true

Result:

Update:
The issue should have been fixed now.
When I add the fetchFilter in the checkout step, it can work as expected.
Result:


Reported to Microsoft and will post back here once resolution available.

@N.Y  Thanks for your update. I have noticed the reported ticket in Developer Community : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/fatal:-could-not-fetch-SHA-from-promisor/10732921 And I will help monitor the update. If there is update, I will update my answer to share the result.

@N.Y  This issue should have been fixed now. I have updated my answer. You can try it in your pipeline and check the result.

OK now it works but throws a different error.
##[warning]Git checkout failed on shallow repository, this might because of git fetch with depth '1' doesn't include the checkout commit 'refs/remotes/origin/f5bd52e0b1350c99097dbf28a7a8985cd55f4be1'. Please reference documentation (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=829603)

@N.Y It seems that you need to set fetchDepth:0 in the checkout step. Refer to this doc about checkout definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines
